# rename files by pulling new names from a file

Tags: bash, rename, command-line-interface

I have a bunch of files that need to be renamed and the new name is in a text file.

Example file name:

```
ASBC_Fishbone_Ia.pdf
```

Example entry in text file:

```
Ia. Propagation—Design Considerations
```

Expected new file name:

```
Ia. Propagation—Design Considerations.pdf
```

or

```
Ia._Propagation—Design_Considerations
```

What would be a good way of going about this using typical linux cli tools? I'm thinking some combination of ls, grep and rename?

Comment: How do you know which name in the file matches which file on disk?

Comment: Are they all pdf-files? Than you could use the pdf metadata like this: pdfinfo file.pdf | grep Title | sed 's/Title:[ ]*//'

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do not allow the script to run if it's not Bash or Bash version is < 4.0 .
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && [[ BASH_VERSINFO -ge 4 ]] || exit 1

# Do not allow presenting glob pattern if no match is found.
shopt -s nullglob

# Use an associative array.
declare -A MAP=() || exit 1

while IFS=$'\t' read -r CODE NAME; do
    # Maps name with code e.g. MAP['Ia']='Propagation—Design Considerations'
    MAP[${CODE%.}]=$NAME
done < /path/to/text_file

# Change directory. Not needed if files are in current directory.
cd "/path/to/dir/containing/files" || exit 1

for FILE in *_*.pdf; do
    # Get code from filename.
    CODE=${FILE##*_} CODE=${CODE%.pdf}

    # Skip if no code was extracted from file.
    [[ -n $CODE ]] || continue

    # Get name from map based from code.
    NAME=${MAP[$CODE]}

    # Skip if no new name was registered based on code.
    [[ -n $NAME ]] || continue

    # Generate new name.
    NEW_NAME="${CODE}. $NAME.pdf"

    # Replace spaces with _ at your preference. Uncomment if wanted.
    # NEW_NAME=${NEWNAME// /_}

    # Rename file. Remove echo if you find it correct already.
    echo mv -- "$FILE" "$NEW_NAME"
done
```